# mongodb/mongoose aggregate with or returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Why does this not work?

I can not get to work with an $or condition. However it returns results, when I simply put the two regex Expessions in a joint statement.

```
Zip.aggregate(

  {
    $or: [
           {$match: {'ort': regExp}},
           {$match: {'ortsteile.ortsteil': regExp}}

    ]
  },

  function(err, results) {

    //returns null

});



// while this returns results:


Zip.aggregate(

  {$match: {'ort': regExp, 'ortsteile.ortsteil': regExp}},

  function(err, results) {

    //returns a list of results

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Zip.aggregate(
  {
    $match: {
        $or : [
            {
                "ort":regExp
            },
            {
                "ortsteile.ortsteil": regExp
            }
        ]
    }
  },

  function(err, results) {

    //returns result

});
```

Comment: Thank you. I would at least have expected an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong.

```
Zip.aggregate({
    $match: {
        $or : [
            { 'ort':regExp },
            { 'ortsteile.ortsteil': regExp }
        ]
    }},
  function(err, results) {
    //your code to handle results
});
```